# How do I use a button on the nav bar to link to another .html.erb file and display it

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So I have a homepage.html.erb that displays a bunch of stuff, but on my nav bar I have hrefs to different html files(using a template). How do I make it so that when I click for example the about button on the navbar, it takes the user to the about.html.erb page? I know I have to use the controller but I don't know if I'm doing it right and not sure how to change the HTML as well. Sorry for the simple question, first time using rails.

Here's the welcome controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def homepage
    render('homepage')
  end

  def about
    render('about')
  end

  def contact
    render('contact')
  end

  def programs
    render('programs')
  end
end
```

And routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/homepage'
  get 'welcome/contact' => 'welcome#contact'
  root 'welcome#homepage'
  resources :welcome
end
```

Sorry for the mess but I've been trying a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

The way it's supposed to work is:

```
get 'path', to: 'controller#action'
```

So my guess is you need this:

```
get 'contact', to: 'welcome#contact'
```

If you request
http://localhost:3000/contact
It would send you to the welcome controller and call the contact method, that in your case would render the partial.

PS: If you don't want to render a partial you need to add a page called 'contact.html.erb' in views/welcome and leave your method empty in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
Read up here. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

**Long answer:**
`$ rake routes` should give you a list of your routes

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
welcome_homepage GET    /welcome/homepage(.:format) welcome#homepage
 welcome_contact GET    /welcome/contact(.:format)  welcome#contact
            root GET    /                           welcome#homepage
   welcome_index GET    /welcome(.:format)          welcome#index
                 POST   /welcome(.:format)          welcome#create
     new_welcome GET    /welcome/new(.:format)      welcome#new
    edit_welcome GET    /welcome/:id/edit(.:format) welcome#edit
         welcome GET    /welcome/:id(.:format)      welcome#show
                 PATCH  /welcome/:id(.:format)      welcome#update
                 PUT    /welcome/:id(.:format)      welcome#update
                 DELETE /welcome/:id(.:format)      welcome#destroy
```

if you look at the Prefix verb you can use view helpers to build urls.

example: In your nav.html.erb file `<%= link_to "Home Page", welcome_homepage_path %>`

Notice how I take the prefix verb and add _path. there is also _url which is best used in mailers. more on that here
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers